# The monitor on my Lenovo Thinkpad suddenly started going black, displaying normally, back and forth (3 cycles avg) when plug in or unplug from charger

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, battery, charger

This just started happening and I’ve found lots of questions and answers on forums with similar phenomenons except none of them go back and forth, that is the display goes black and then back to normal, a few times before ultimately displaying correctly.

The effect is very similar to when you connect or disconnect an external monitor except in that case it doesn’t go back and forth a few times (in my experience that is). Even though ultimately, after this cycle, the laptop displays normally and all is good, what is worrying and strange is that it’s when I’m unplugging or plugging the battery charging cable. And also that it has just started after years of owning the computer has me a bit troubled. Battery passes any health check. I haven’t changed any settings recently.

So any ideas as far as what could cause this sort of behavior? I’m going to do another back up of my data asap just in case my laptop decides to kick the bucket suddenly.

Thanks in advance for ideas and feel free to ask any questions about specs, etc. it’s Lenovo Thinkpad p1 gen 2. Hybrid graphics with intel GPU and nvidia Quadro T1000.

Comment: It could be the display, the backlight, or the cable assembly.  Plug in an external monitor.  If an external monitor is more reliable then your laptop monitor is certainly suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer on my own. Looking through settings and display and remembered that this laptop has an option to use HDR for anything I run or view that supports it. I had enabled it the other day the same time that I disabled battery saver and changed the power mode type to the middle setting for the battery.

I turned HDR off and put battery saver back on and all is good again. I think the HDR just needs more power and whenever I unplugged or plugged in the charging cable the it messed with the how the HDR was getting or using power from the battery. The power mode setting is also dependent on whether the laptop is plugged in or not.

Just an example of me being stupid really and forgetting that I had enabled the HDR setting. I'll take being stupid over needing to buy a new laptop any day.